# How to make it in Qt that the MainWindow's background image does not override child widget's

Tags: css, qt, qtstylesheets

I have made an app in Qt. Just for plain coolness, I'm trying to add a background to the app,
by adding the following stylesheet:

```
// in the stylesheet of "centralwidget"
background-image: url(:/background/assets/background/matrix.jpg)
```

Instead of what I was expecting (the background image goes behind the widgets), it has overridden
every widget's background:
[With background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JL6Tf.jpg)

[Without background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6lT6.png)

Comment: Can you make this an [mcve]?

Comment: check the last two posts of this thread : https://forum.qt.io/topic/112442/avoiding-background-image-of-main-window-in-child-widgets/10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using a stylesheet on a parent widget applies it on all its childs in qt:
so the solution is to specify the widget's class name:
(ex for a QFrame)

```
frame->setStyleSheet("QFrame{ background-image: url(image_path) }")
```

or more precisely use `widget->setObjectName("objectName")`:

```
widget->setObejectName("objectName");
widget->setStyleSheet("#objectName{ background-image: url(image_path) }")
```